# extract a number from first line .rtf file

Tags: numbers, extract

I would need to extract a number from the first line of a .rtf document.
The first line is:

1 of 51 DOCUMENTS

I need to extract the number 51.

How can I do? (Probably easy question but I am not good at textual analysis yet)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The implementation will often be language specific but in general you would likely want to use a regex.  I would suggest adding a tag for the language you want to do this in.